# bootstrap button group select any two checkbox from many

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have to select any 2 checkbox from 4-5 check-boxes. for making checkbox I am using bootstrap.

below is my code

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" checked> Checkbox 1 (pre-checked)
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checkbox 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checkbox 3
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checkbox 4
  </label>
</div>
```

but I want that I can select maximum of 2 check-boxes. and others are need to be disabled

I am using http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio for this and for that when i am click on particular label than disable other  label and also click event

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First add a class `<input type="checkbox" class="ch" autocomplete="off">`
use `.change() event handler to trigger the code on check/uncheck of checkbox.

```
$('.ch').change(function() {
      $($('.btn-group').find("input[type='checkbox']")).each(function() {
        $(this).attr("disabled", false);
      });
      var check = $($('.btn-group').find("input[type='checkbox']:checked")).length;
      if (check > 1) {
        $('.btn-group').find("input[type='checkbox']").not(":checked").attr("disabled", true);
      }
    });
```

Here is an example in jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/jagrati16/q8jo77c2/

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the following code to do what you want.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  var number = $('.btn-group').find("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
  if (number > 1) {
    $('.btn-group').find("input[type='checkbox']").not(":checked").attr("disabled", true);
  }else {
    $('.btn-group').find("input[type='checkbox']").attr("disabled", false);
  }
});
```

I have created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/89stq7os/) too. I hope this solves your problem.